# Understanding the following lemma to prove the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

> Proof of Lemma. Since $f$ is differentiable at $c$, we have that:
>   $$f(x) = f(c)+f'(c)(x-c)+o(|x-c|),$$
>
> as $x-c \to 0$. Suppose that $f'(c) \neq 0.$

What does the function $o$ represent and why is $f(x)$ equal to that?

Answer (score 3):

$o(|x-c|)$ stands for an arbitrary function with $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{o(h)}h=0$ (see [Big Oh notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) to lear about it and its relatives). Thus the equation merely states that $f(x)-f(c)-f'(c)(x-c)$ is a function of $x$ that tends to $0$ as $x\to c$ faster than $|x-c|$ does. This is just a rewording of the definition of $f'(c)$, namely $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\to 0$ as $x\to c$.

Comment: I don't follow when you say as $x \rightarrow c$ faster than $|x - c|$ does.

Answer (score 0):

It's using "little-oh" notation. You can find information about that on the [wiki article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations) as well as [MathWorld here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html). It's essentially saying that whatever is not represented by the first two terms on the RHS is bounded very strongly by $|x-c|$.